# Including primary key in django url for included namespaces?

Tags: django

I have the following in my urls.py:

```
ta_patterns = [
    path('no_pk_needed/', view1.as_view()),
    path('pk_needed/<int:campaign_pk>/', view2.as_view()),
]
campaign_patterns = [
    path('ta/',
         include((ta_patterns, 'ta'), namespace='ta')),
]
```

This generates the following url:

```
campaign/ta/no_pk_needed/
campaign/ta/pk_needed/<int:campaign_pk>/
```

I would like `campaign_pk` to be as close to `campaign/` as possible. Ideally, I would like to achieve this:

```
campaign/ta/no_pk_needed/
campaign/<int:campaign_pk>/ta/pk_needed/
```

But I don't know how this could be done using my current pattern.

### How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to combine the two rather than using an include.

```
campaign_patterns = [
    path('ta/no_pk_needed/', view1.as_view()),
    path('<int:campaign_pk>/ta/pk_needed/', view2.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: so I won't be able to use "campaign:ta:view1" in reverse?

Comment: I appreciate your solution but this doesn't meet my requirements